# Facebook permission window with "{App name} would like to access your data at any time."

Tags: facebook, permissions, window

we are using Facebook C# SKD 5.3.2 and we are using server side authentication. We are asking email permission only.
However, the permission window shows the following:

> "{App name} will receive the following info: your public profile, friend list and email address. {App name} would like to access your data at any time."

The first part is OK, but we don't want to show the second sentence about accessing data at any time since it may discourage users from installing our app. It sounds as if we were asking offline_access but we are not, and when I check access token after permission is granted, it has email and user_friends permissions only as it's supposed to. when I check the URL, it looks like the following http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=email&state=eyJyI... and it has "email" only as a value of scope query string.
At the permission settings under developers.facebook.com, we don't have any permissions set since we are asking email permission in the code. Interestingly, sometimes it does not show the second sentence about accessing data. It seems it's random. I'm not sure exactly when it started behaving like this but I think it started when Facebook changed permission dialog to use your app icon and your profile photo with white background (about 3 months? ago).

Comment: Was your app whitelisted in some way for special access to the API? The string you're referring to should no longer apply to any apps except for those doing ads management or a small subset of older apps which retain access to the 'offline_access' permissions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Our app is white-listed for ads API, but as I mentioned in the post, we are passing "email" only for authentication, and after the permission granted, it doesn't contain offline_access permission, and it's correct since we don't ask for it. Only permission dialog is incorrect. I'll report this as a bug on facebook.

Comment: I saw you filed a bug about this on the bug tracker and I've closed it out - this is intentional for ads API apps as they implicitly receive persistent ('offline access') tokens

Comment: I read explanation from Facebook and I understand it. Thank you